# Не корректно отображaется цвет фона html&css

Tags: html, css

[image: Пример белой подложки по фоном]

Верхняя часть. Вставлена фоновая фотография и также прописан цвет  черный 
`background:#000 url("") no-repeat`. 
Но фоновая фотография заканчивается, а цвет не отображается. Не понимаю почему?

Вот код — но в нем нет фотографии поэтому выглядит все корректно. 
Но на оригинальном сайте фон не отображается

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    min-width:960px;
    max-height:1800px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:'PT Sans', 'sans-serif';
    color:white;
    background:#000 url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0%;
    max-width:1800px;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> Если наряду с фоновыми изображениями требуется задать цвет фона
>   элемента, он указывается в последнюю очередь после перечисления.

[Источник на русском языке](https://webref.ru/css/background) и на английском [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background#Syntax).

В этом случае используйте указание цвета фона в конце:

```
background: url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0% #000;
```

Comment: Нет не получается все равно.